# fetch api metodo GET com Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

Fala galera bom dia, estou com um `form` que o usuário digita cpf e ra e recebe o seu `id_registration`, estou tentando fazer isso com ajax, porém sempre retorna `500 Internal Server Error`, segue minha linha de código:

***recovery-id.js:***

```js
const recoveryButtom = document.querySelector('#recovery-id');
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
recoveryButtom.onclick = recoveryID;

function recoveryID() {
    
    let csrfToken;
    for (let input of inputs) {
        if (input.name === 'csrfmiddlewaretoken') {
            csrfToken = input.value;
        }
    }
    
    fetch('/recuperar-id', {
        headers:{
        'Content-type': 'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken': csrfToken
        },
    })
        .then(function(sucess){
            console.log(sucess);
        })
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

***views.py:***

```js
def get_id(request):

    form = StudentForm(request.GET or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        student = Student.objects.filter(cpf=data['cpf']).filter(ra=data['ra']).first()

        if not student:
            return JsonResponse({'studentNotFound': 'O aluno não encontrado'}, status=400)
        
        return render(request, 'index.html', {'student':student})

    return JsonResponse({'student':student})
```

se alguém puder me ajudar serei muito grato, valeu galera!!!

Comment: Se retorna erro 500, quer dizer que há um erro nesta função, o que o _debug_ do Django mostra a respeito?

Answer (score 1):

No teu código existem algumas coisas que não são consistentes:

- No Javascript você está pegando os valores do seu input mas não transmite seus dados para a URL ou para o corpo da requisição. Por exemplo: `fetch('/recuperar-id/' + csrftoken)`. Você apenas definiu alguns headers da requisição. Lembre de ajustar a URL no urls.py caso necessário.
- Já que vc não está passando nenhuma informação no Javascript, o DJango não tem como receber nada e o form nunca será válido já que request.GET não possui nenhum dado Pegar.
- Já que o form não é válido, a execução pula para essa linha: `return JsonResponse({'student':student})` e perceba que a variável 'student' não está declarada para este escopo e é provavelmente isso que ocasiona este erro.

O que eu aconselho que vc faça:

1. Revise seu Javascript para enviar os dados corretamente para o Back-end
2. Com o Javascript funcionando, pegue as informações direitinho, trabalhe com o formulário e execute sua lógica

Obs.: Coloque esse último return do seu código que causa os erros em um 'else' para vc poder fazer isso: `return JsonResponse({'student': ''})` ou algum outro formato que sua aplicação deva aceitar e assim evita quebrar a execução

Comment: realmente estavam faltando algumas coisas, eu resolvi enviar os dados via POST e receber o `Id_registration` na response, demorou um pouco mas consegui resolver o problema, vou colocar aqui a respota